# Buttons added to UINavigationController don't show up until after navigating to next page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I apologize in advance because I'm a complete beginner when it comes to Objective-C and iOS development, however I am having an issue that is really puzzling me. I have this code in a view which I'd like to put on something called "Home Page," which shows up after the "Login" page.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                             initWithTitle: @"Sign Out"
                                             style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                             target: self
                                             action: @selector(logout_Action:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithTitle:@"New"
                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                              target:self
                                              action:@selector(new_Action:)];
    [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem release];
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem release];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
```

Unfortunately, that "Sign Out" button isn't showing up until the user navigates to the NEXT page, i.e. by clicking that "New" button that I've declared.

The interesting thing is that the *rightBarButtonItem* actually appears to be working just fine. Any pointers to how to fix this would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithTitle: @"Sign Out"
                                         style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                         target: self
                                         action: @selector(logout_Action:)];
```

This sets what the back button will be to return to this view controller, not the current back button that's showing. This is why the signout button shows up when you go to the "New" page, because you just changed the back button that will go back to the home screen.

So if you want to change the back button, put this code in the PREVIOUS view controller, the one that leads to the home page. Example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // In view controller that comes BEFORE the "Home page"

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                             initWithTitle: @"Sign Out"
                                                     style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                    target: homeScreenController
                                                    action: @selector(logout_Action:)];
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, but it's possible to get to the home page a few ways: 1) by logging in, 2) by going back from another page. In the second case, where do I set backBarButtonItem?

Comment: If you go from login page->home screen -> another page, then from the other page hit back to go to the home screen, the back button should still be the same as it was before.

Comment: Also, the target needs to be the view controller that has the "logout_Action" method, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

Comment: oops- here is the flow: [log in]->[home]->[new doc form]->[document] --- NOW, upon hitting 'back' on [document] the user should go back to [home], not the new doc form.

Comment: so I guess what I'm asking is if there is a way to go back TWO pages, which looks like is answered by this question. thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122988/calling-popviewcontrolleranimated-twice

Comment: Yep, glad you figured everything out!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you set the back button to be your sign out button,

try to replace

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem

with

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

Comment: Hmm, that works- but it now has the button shape, rather than the Back shape.

Comment: It looks like there might not be any way around this other than creating an image and using a custom button there. I'll have to rework  the way I push views onto the stack, I guess so that I can push the Back button appropriately. If I put the Sign Out button on the stack in the Login page, and then some user gets back to the Login page, will the Sign Out button be restored automatically? (i.e. is it kept along with the stack)

Comment: You can only have a "native" back button if you have a view controller to go back to in the stack, yes.
Please accept the answer if you feel it's answering your question.